# Retrieving dissimilar data using WHERE NOT in the joins?

Tags: sql

I need to retrieve the name of those departments in which no students are enrolled.

Table: **department**

```
dept_id    dept_name
      1    IT
      2    Electrical
      3    Civil
      4    Mechanical
      5    Chemical
```

Table: **stud_member**

```
  f_name    dept_id   age
      AB         2      19 
    Rose         3      22
     May         1      20
    Noor         1      21
    Haya         1      19
    April        3      23
  Sakina         2      20
```

For example the names of mechanical and chemical. I have written this query for it using outer join (explicitly maybe?) But is shows an error.

please tell me that why i cannot write:

```
SELECT dept_id, dept_name
FROM department
LEFT JOIN stud_member ON (WHERE NOT department.dept_id = stud_member.dept_id);
```

I will be grateful if anyone will tell me the correct answer!

Comment: `select ... from t1 left join t2 on t1.a = t2.b...`

Comment: SQLSERVER OR ORACLE OR ANY OTHER DB

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NOT IN vs NOT EXISTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173041/not-in-vs-not-exists)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `dept_id` in `stud_member` can not be `NULL` which is true when `dept_id` is a `FOREIGN KEY`

```
SELECT dept_id, dept_name
FROM department
WHERE dept_id NOT IN (SELECT dept_id FROM stud_member);
```

as suggested using NOT EXISTS does not have this problem

```
SELECT d.dept_id, d.dept_name
FROM department d
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM stud_member s WHERE d.dept_id = s.dept_id);
```

Comment: Will return an empty result if there is a stud_member with dept_id null. Do `NOT EXISTS` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can select all departments where Right part of Left JOIN is NULL

```
SELECT d.dept_id, d.dept_name
FROM department d
   LEFT JOIN stud_member sm ON d.dept_id = sm.dept_id
WHERE sm.dept_id IS NULL
```